# sorting multiple fields of the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I have a sorting function that, according to the specified table, should filter the data in the order I need..

```
public function getOrderBy(): array
    {
        $sortOrder = in_array(
            $this->fieldSort,
            ['price_desc'],
            true
        ) ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;

        $by = in_array(
            $this->fieldSort,
            ['price_asc', 'price_desc'],
            true
        ) ? 'hotel_price.price' : null;

        return $by ? [$by => $sortOrder] : [];
    }
```

```
$query = self::getActive();

$query->select([self::tableName() . '.*']);

if ($validate && !empty($filter->getOrderBy())) {
  $query->joinWith('hotelPrice');
  $query->orderBy($filter->getOrderBy());
}
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

As a result, sorting for price_asc works as it should, I get values ​​from minimum to large.

But there are some problems with price_desc. It sorts, but not quite right.

The fact is that here an array is taken from the table, let's say for hotel_id = 1, it has values ​​2 and 3. And sorting works by the first element of the array. For price_asc, this is normal, but for price_desc, you need to make sure that sorting starts from the last element of the array.

But I still can’t figure out how to do this, do I need to do this in the sort function itself, or will I have to dig deeper?

**UPDATE**

It is the array of values, let's say now hotel_id = 5, that has an array of price values ​​[1, 2, 3], and now sorting for asc and desc starts from the first element of the array. And I need for desc to start from the last.

The only idea I have so far is to sort the id column along with the price_range column.

But how do I pass such a value to SQL. Should be something like:

```
$by = 'hotel_price.id', 'hotel_price.price';
```

If I make DESC for the id, then the last value will be in the first place in the table and the array will look like this price values ​​[3, 2, 1]

I'll try to explain again, my function, which is in the code, does the following:

> SELECT DISTINCT hotels.*, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY hotel_price.price DESC

I need to make it so that sorting is applied to id along with price.

And the response should be something like:

> ORDER BY hotel_price.id DESC, hotel_price.price DESC

Need to apply double sorting.

I know it's quite possible for different tables, but is it possible to do it for one table but for different fields?

I output something like this in the query, but in the end only the first field is sorted:

> ORDER BY hotel_price.id DESC, hotel_price.price DESC

## ===========================

1. I have a table like this

[image]

I need two fields here, id and price.

When I apply sorting by only one price field or one id field, then everything works.

2. Here is the query I am running

> SELECT DISTINCT hotels.*, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY hotel_price.id DESC, hotel_price.price DESC

3. I expect that at first my table will be sorted by id and it will look like this

[image]

And the second sorting by the price field will be applied to this sorted table by id

4. But in the end, only the first sort by id works for me, that is, the table becomes the same as in the last screenshot, but the second sort by price is not applied to it.
5. **Addition**
   If I send a request like this

> SELECT DISTINCT hotels.*, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY hotel_price.price DESC, hotel_price.id DESC

Ie, first I'll try to sort by price, then by ID, then on the contrary, it sorts by price, but by id it's gone.

In short, sorting is always applied only to the first field, although I send two in the request.

## ===========================

I added my table to the post. And when displaying on the frontend, let's say we take a hotel with ID 5, and it has an array with prices [1, 2, 3].

And when I sort hotels by price before hotels are always sorted by price where he takes the first value. In this case it's 1.

When I sort by ASC, everything is displayed correctly, but when I sort by DESC, the first price value is still taken in the sort, and then the sort looks incorrect.

That is, to sort by DESC, I need to get the array with prices from the table in the reverse order [3, 2, 1], so that the largest value is taken for sorting.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252140/discussion-on-question-by-broken-heart-sorting-multiple-fields-of-the-same-table); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then a second sort is needed.

This is how your first criteria would be price:

```
public function getOrderBy(): array
    {
        $sortOrder = in_array(
            $this->fieldSort,
            ['price_desc'],
            true
        ) ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;

        $by = in_array(
            $this->fieldSort,
            ['price_asc', 'price_desc'],
            true
        ) ? 'hotel_price.price' : null;

        return $by ? [$by => $sortOrder, 'hotel_price.id' => SORT_ASC] : ['hotel_price.id' => SORT_ASC];
    }
```

And this is the other way around:

```
public function getOrderBy(): array
    {
        $sortOrder = in_array(
            $this->fieldSort,
            ['price_desc'],
            true
        ) ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;

        $by = in_array(
            $this->fieldSort,
            ['price_asc', 'price_desc'],
            true
        ) ? 'hotel_price.price' : null;

        return $by ? ['hotel_price.id' => SORT_ASC, $by => $sortOrder] : ['hotel_price.id' => SORT_ASC];
    }
```

EDIT

Basically you have two sort criterias. It's important to understand that when  we sort the r1 and r2 records, then we determine the order of these records, but in the result set r1 and r2 have a single order. We do not order individual fields; we order whole records based on some sort criterias. A sort criteria of

```
ORDER BY foo desc, bar desc
```

in plain words means the following:

**
If r1.foo <> r2.foo then the order of r1 and r2 is determined by foo descendingly
else the order of r1 and r2 is determined by bar descendingly
**

I have constructed a test case for this purpose.

## Data build

```
create table hotels(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    price int not null,
    hotel_id int not null
);

insert into hotels(price, hotel_id)
values
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 4),
(1, 5),
(2, 5),
(3, 5),
(2, 6);
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99f449/5

Below I discuss several cases, please look into the code and especially to the comments.

## order by id desc, price desc

```
/*
This orders by id, price
We expect for any r1, r2 records that
- if r1.id > r2.id, then r1 is before r2
- if r1.id = r2.id, then we order them by price
    - if r1.price > r2.price then r1 is before r2
    - if r1.price = r2.price then our sort criteria does not determine their order
    - if r1.price < r2.price then r1 is after r2
- if r2.id < r2.id, then r1 is after r2
As we can see above, r1 and r2 have a single order, which is determined by id and it would only be
determined by price if r1.id = r2.id, so, if there is a tie in the order of ids, then price is
the tiebreaker. Yet, the id field is unique (it's even a primary key), so we never end up using
price as an order criteria
*/
select *
from hotels
order by id desc, price desc;
```

[image]

## order by price desc, id desc

```
/*
This orders by price, id
We expect for any r1, r2 records that
- if r1.price > r2.price, then r1 is before r2
- if r1.price = r2.price, then
    - if r1.id > r2.id, then r1 is before r2
    - if r1.id = r2.id, then our sort criteria does not determine their order
    - if r1.id < r2.id, then r1 is after r2
- if r1.price < r2.price, then r1 is after r2
So, our first sort criteria is price and our records are ordered by price, except when their prices
are equal, in which case we break the tie by our second sorting criteria
*/

select *
from hotels
order by price desc, id desc;
```

[image]

## order by hotel_id desc, price desc

```
/*
This orders by hotel_id, price
We expect for any r1, r2 records that
- if r1.hotel_id > r2.hotel_id, then r1 is before r2
- if r1.hotel_id = r2.hotel_id, then we order them by price
    - if r1.price > r2.price then r1 is before r2
    - if r1.price = r2.price then our sort criteria does not determine their order
    - if r1.price < r2.price then r1 is after r2
- if r2.hotel_id < r2.hotel_id, then r1 is after r2
As we can see above, r1 and r2 have a single order, which is determined by hotel_id and it would 
only be determined by price if r1.hotel_id = r2.hotel_id, so, if there is a tie in the order of
hotel ids, then price is the tiebreaker.
*/

select *
from hotels
order by hotel_id desc, price desc;
```

[image]

## order by price desc, hotel_id desc

```
/*
This orders by price, hotel_id
We expect for any r1, r2 records that
- if r1.price > r2.price, then r1 is before r2
- if r1.price = r2.price, then
    - if r1.hotel_id > r2.hotel_id, then r1 is before r2
    - if r1.hotel_id = r2.hotel_id, then our sort criteria does not determine their order
    - if r1.hotel_id < r2.hotel_id, then r1 is after r2
- if r1.price < r2.price, then r1 is after r2
So, our first sort criteria is price and our records are ordered by price, except when their prices
are equal, in which case we break the tie by our second sorting criteria
*/

select *
from hotels
order by price desc, hotel_id desc;
```

[image]

Comment: I did so and in the request it leaves me `SELECT DISTINCT hotels.*, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY hotel_price.id DESC, hotel_price.price DESC`

Comment: But in the end, it sorts only by the id field, if I do the opposite, it will sort only by price. I don't understand why it doesn't sort by the second field

Comment: @brokenheart this query indeed sort by both. That is, it sorts by the first sorting criteria first and for records where that value is equal, the second sort is applied. Can you provide two record values along with the exact sort criteria you have and explain what their order is and why it is wrong?

Comment: If I initially set hotel_price.id DESC, then I sort it only by id, if I put hotel_price.price DESC first, then I sort it only by the price field

Comment: And I need to make it so that it is first sorted by id, and then sorting by price is applied to this sort by id

Comment: And as a result, the request takes me two fields for sorting hotel_price.id DESC, hotel_price.price DESC, but in the end it sorts only by the first one, in this case by id

Comment: @brokenheart In order to help you further I need: 1. An example of two records which fails your expectations; 2. The query that has been executed, especially the sort clause; 3. The expected result; 4. The actual result. Can you provide all four?

Comment: Added all paragraphs to the end of the post

Comment: @brokenheart I have read your edits to your question. There are basically two cases. Case 1: `hotel_price.id DESC, hotel_price.price DESC`. This sort works in the following way: if we have r1 and r2 and their ids are different, then their order will be determined by id. In case of a tie, when r1 and r2 has the same id, then their order is determined by price. Since any different r1, r2 records have different ids, if we use id as the first sort criteria, then there will be no ties and the price order will be completely ignored.

Comment: @brokenheart Case 2: `hotel_price.price DESC, hotel_price.id DESC`. This order by determines the order by price as the first criteria for any r1 and r2 records. If they happen to have the same price, then the tiebreaker is the id.

Comment: Sort by hotel_price.id was one of my implementation options, I added what I needed at the end of the post. Maybe there is another way to not sort by hotel_price.id?

Comment: @brokenheart `hotel_price.id` is unique. If you sort by it as the first criteria, then further sort criterias will never be applied. It's likely that you wanted to sort by `hotel_id` instead of `id`. I have added extensive experimental content along with explanations to my answer as well as a link to SQLFiddle where you can actually test this. Please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me a lot. Is it possible to make it so that sorting by only one price field, but at the same time that the largest value for sorting DESC is taken in the price column?

Comment: Something like when I sort by price DESC, I get its maximum value, like this `max('hotel_price.price') => SORT_DESC`

Comment: @brokenheart If you want to sort hotels by their max price descendingly, that would be something like `select hotel_id, max(price) from hotel_price group by hotel_id order by max(price) desc`. This groups your hotel prices by hotel_id and sorts by max price descendingly. I do not have your ORM at my disposal to play with, but you will need to convert this query into your preferred format if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Now I am getting this error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1630 FUNCTION restaurant_price_range.max does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
The SQL being executed was:`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT hotels.*, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY hotel_price.max(price) DESC`

Comment: The second mistake, if the request is made a little differently `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3029 Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query
The SQL being executed was:`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT hotels.*, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY max(hotel_price.price) DESC`

Comment: @brokenheart There is no such thing as `hotel_price.max(price)`, so your first query will fail for not finding a function that does not exist, which is expected. Your second query is closer to the desired query, as it properly calls `max(hotel_price.price)`, yet, a `group by` is missing, so your query is unaggregated and the aggregate function of `max` in the `order by` clause requires your query to be aggregated. The reason is simple: if you do not aggregate your query, then `max(hotel_price.price)` will evaluate to the single greatest price value and sorting that single record makes no sense

Comment: @brokenheart Your `DISTINCT` keyword also suggests that you want aggregation, so let's ` modify your query accordingly: `SELECT <your fields>, FROM hotel LEFT JOIN hotel_price ON hotels.id = hotel_price.hotel_id GROUP BY hotels.id WHERE (hotels.status=1) ORDER BY hotel_price.max(price) DESC`. 1. <your fields> is something you will need to define; 2. I removed `DISTINCT`; 3. I added a `GROUP BY hotels.id` to make sure the query is aggregated.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to modify the getOrderBy function to sort by the last element of the array when sorting in descending order

Try this using the array_reverse function :

```
public function getOrderBy(): array
{
    $sortOrder = in_array(
        $this->fieldSort,
        ['price_desc'],
        true
    ) ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC;

    $by = in_array(
        $this->fieldSort,
        ['price_asc', 'price_desc'],
        true
    ) ? 'hotel_price.price' : null;

    if ($sortOrder === SORT_DESC) {
        $by = "SUBSTRING_INDEX(hotel_price.price, ',', -1)";
    }

    return $by ? [$by => $sortOrder] : [];
}
```

Comment: This option is working, thanks, but is there any way to do it through MAX?

Comment: Yes, you can replace the : if ($sortOrder === SORT_DESC) {
        $by = "SUBSTRING_INDEX(hotel_price.price, ',', -1)";
    }

By : if ($sortOrder === SORT_DESC) {
        $by = "MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(hotel_price.price, ',', -1))";
    }

Comment: although I made a mistake, sorry, this solution does not help, it sorts as before

Comment: Even the first one ?

Comment: yes, the first and second time

Comment: okay sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Huh?  Does `price` have more thing one thing in it?